# How to replace ctx in app_commands? - Discord.py

Tags: discord.py

I'm using the code:

```py
@app_commands.command(name='command', description='desc command')
async def command_(self, interaction: discord.Interaction):
    #body command
```

For example I need to know the author who sent the team. Usually (if I use not App_Commands), I in the argument of the command of the command set `ctx` parameter:

```py
@commands.command(name='command', description='desc command')
async def command_(self, ctx):
    await ctx.send(ctx.author.name)
```

But `app_commands` does not support `ctx`. So, how can you replace the `ctx` in app_commands?

Somehow yes, in my opinion should look code look:

```py
@app_commands.command(name='command', description='desc command')
async def command_(self, interaction: discord.Interaction):
    ctx = <replacement of ctx>
    await interaction.response.send_message(ctx.author.name)
```

Don't know, it is probably a [MessageInteracion](https://Don%27t%20know%20it%20is%20probably%20a%20messageinteration), but I don't know how to extract information from it like from `ctx`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many things can be done from the interaction but you can use
`ctx = await bot.get_context(interaction)` to get the context.

Just note (happened to me) that if you want to transform your old commands to app_commands, check that the messages are sent quickly enough, or you will get an error that didn't happen with `@commands.command()`

Comment: Thank you everything. I do not have such teams, so I have not met with such a mistake